# My phone does not show the call+SMS option and I want to block certain pnone numbers

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, call-sms-filter

I am trying to block certain phone numbers but when I go to settings I can't see the CALL+SMS option. What should I do? Is there any other way?

I am using a Lumia 520.

Comment: provide the OS version

Comment: @Ravimallya The tag 8.1 means that the phone is running Windows phone 8.1. The option remained the same in all minor versions of 8.1. What is the use of asking addtional details if there is no use for it.